# Nested Resource with Devise - Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to setup a profiles controller to work with devise registered members.

I've created the `Profile` model & controller and added a `one-to-one relationship` by adding `belongs_to :member` to my **profile.rb** model and `has_one :profile` in my **member.rb** model.

To create the nested resource I used:

```
devise_for :members, :path => "accounts",:path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }

resources :members do
  resources :profiles
end
```

Calling `rake routes` outputs

```
     member_profiles GET    /members/:member_id/profiles(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"profiles"}
                     POST   /members/:member_id/profiles(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"profiles"}
  new_member_profile GET    /members/:member_id/profiles/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"profiles"}
 edit_member_profile GET    /members/:member_id/profiles/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profiles"}
      member_profile GET    /members/:member_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}
                     PUT    /members/:member_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"profiles"}
                     DELETE /members/:member_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"profiles"}
```

Going to `localhost:3000/members/1/profiles` in the browser correctly routes me to the `profiles#index` page, but when I try calling `member_profiles_path` it fails with the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"profiles"}
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here? I'm using rails 3.0.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since this is a has_one association, have you tried using resource rather than resources?

```
resources :members do
  resource :profile
end
```

You should then be able to do something like this:

```
link_to "Profile", member_profile_path(@member)
```