# Rails3 + Devise: When to nest resource in devise_for & nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

1. When should I nest routes in the `devise_for` block? Please give one or two examples to show the use case. (Routes #1)
2. If `:foo_object` is associated with `:users` so `:user` has_one `:foo_object`, do I need to nest `:foo_object` under `:users`? (Routes #2) `:users` is the devise `:users` model.

Routes #1:

```
devise_for :users  
resource :foo_object
```

Routes #2:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users do      
  resource :foo_object
end
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following example:

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'accounts'

resources :users do
    resources :orders
end
```

The above means that the authentication path would be `"/accounts/sign_in"`, `"/accounts_sign_up"`etc.. Some may not know that it is important to acknowledge that the `devise_for :users` doesn't **actually** map to the `UsersController` and the model. Its not even a resource route, even though many beleive it looks like it. Which is why we can't treat it like the following:

```
devise_for :users do 
   resources: somereosouce
end
```

All `devise_for` does is map the following routes:

```
# Session routes for Authenticatable (default)
     new_user_session GET  /users/sign_in                    {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"new"}
         user_session POST /users/sign_in                    {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"create"}
 destroy_user_session GET  /users/sign_out                   {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"destroy"}

# Password routes for Recoverable, if User model has :recoverable configured
    new_user_password GET  /users/password/new(.:format)     {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"new"}
   edit_user_password GET  /users/password/edit(.:format)    {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"edit"}
        user_password PUT  /users/password(.:format)         {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"update"}
                      POST /users/password(.:format)         {:controller=>"devise/passwords", :action=>"create"}

# Confirmation routes for Confirmable, if User model has :confirmable configured
new_user_confirmation GET  /users/confirmation/new(.:format) {:controller=>"devise/confirmations", :action=>"new"}
    user_confirmation GET  /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:controller=>"devise/confirmations", :action=>"show"}
                      POST /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:controller=>"devise/confirmations", :action=>"create"}
```

So in saying that you could do the following but would have some conflicts:

```
devise_for :users 

resource :users do 
   resource :foo_object
end
```

A little bit on nested resources, if you have something like the following:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_object
end

class FooObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
end
```

Then your nested resource would be

```
   resource :users do 
     resource :foo_object 
   end
```

Hopefully this clears things up. Also you may want to have a read of [Nested Resource with Devise - Rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785684/nested-resource-with-devise-rails3)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the `devise_for` question. Best explanation I've read!

Comment: For Q #2, I know that's what I'd do to nest the resource... I guess the question is more of is it necessary or do I have to nest the resource for associated models for this case? Because in this case, I can use `current_user` in the controller and build/update the `:foo_object` model. I'm wondering if there are consequences to doing it this way.

Comment: @HM1 it isn't exactly necessary no, but if you want to define some logic your application then yes. Its a cleaner way of grouping your resources. However in your case you know that a `user` is associated with `foo_object`. So that when you perform an action to a `user` you would be performing an action `foo_object` also. So your URL would potentially look like something like this `/users/3/foo_object/4` Another reason why it would be necessary to have nested routes is because its RESTful one of the important principles in Rails.