# difficulty with member routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

UPDATE: This was all a horrible mistake - I was updating the wrong routes file!
this does work: `get 'users/:id/groups/' => 'users#groups'`

I'd like to be able to see groups that belong to a specific user but I'm having trouble setting up a route that would resolve to:

`/users/:id/groups`

for some reason. I'm guessing devise is getting in the way, perhaps.

i've tried the following:

```
resources :users 

match '/users/:id/groups', to: 'users#groups', via: :get
```

and

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'groups'
  end
end
```

such a route never shows up when i call `rake routes`:

```
$ rake routes
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
              groups GET    /groups(.:format)                    groups#index
                     POST   /groups(.:format)                    groups#create
           new_group GET    /groups/new(.:format)                groups#new
          edit_group GET    /groups/:id/edit(.:format)           groups#edit
               group GET    /groups/:id(.:format)                groups#show
                     PATCH  /groups/:id(.:format)                groups#update
                     PUT    /groups/:id(.:format)                groups#update
                     DELETE /groups/:id(.:format)                groups#destroy
            calendar GET    /calendar(/:year(/:month))(.:format) calendar#index {:year=>/\d{4}/, :month=>/\d{1,2}/}
                root GET    /                                    calendar#index
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)        devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)       devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)              registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                     registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)             registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                     registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                     registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                     registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)        devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)    devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)        devise/confirmations#show
  accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)   devise/invitations#edit
  remove_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/remove(.:format)   devise/invitations#destroy
         user_invitation POST   /users/invitation(.:format)          devise/invitations#create
     new_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)      devise/invitations#new
                        PATCH  /users/invitation(.:format)          devise/invitations#update
                        PUT    /users/invitation(.:format)          devise/invitations#update
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                     users#index
                          POST   /users(.:format)                     users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                 users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)            users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                 users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                 users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                 users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                 users#destroy
                  events GET    /events(.:format)                    events#index
                         POST   /events(.:format)                    events#create
               new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                events#new
              edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)           events#edit
                   event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                events#show
                         PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                events#update
                         PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                events#update
                         DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                events#destroy
```

Comment: Can you post your entire routes.rb?  Those should both work...

Comment: yes - sorry i forgot to mention i'm using devise. (updated post)

Comment: precedence does not seem to have an affect

Comment: Using devise prevents you from nesting resources in the traditional sense. Take a look at this question for more information and a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349666/rails3-devise-when-to-nest-resource-in-devise-for-nested-resources

Comment: Ah, you're using devise...

Comment: @Dan, Not sure if that only applies to rails 3 (i'm using 4.0.1) but the suggestions in that question don't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you specifying member when you're trying to nest the resource? Did you try simply

```
resources :users do
  resources :groups, only: :index
end
```

Comment: but this will route `/users/:id/groups` to `groups#index`. i'd like it to route to `users#my_groups`. Or am I mistaken. I think I'm unclear on the difference between a nested resource and a member.

Comment: also - doing this does not show a new route in my `rake routes` call.

Comment: Ah okay, so you're trying to get a my_groups page rather than nest a groups resource. Oh by the way I believe 'match' is deprecated in rails 4. You need to do it like "get '/users/:id/groups', to: 'users#groups'" - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: or "get 'users/:id/groups/ => 'users#groups'"