# Nested resource while using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I am using devise for my User model. I generated this model using devise generator. All the routes worked fine with:

```
  devise_for :users
```

Now, I added the Farm model that belongs to User. In my Farm model, I have:

```
  belongs_to:user
```

In my User model, I have:

```
  has_one:farm
```

Also, in my Farm migration, I have:

```
  t.references:user
```

So, all of the associations are in order as far as I know. Problem emerges when I put this in my routes:

```
   resources :users do
    resource :farms
   end
```

All of the sudden, whichever route I try, I get:

```
   uninitialized constant UsersController
```

Even the routes for sign in, sing up, etc.. Routes that worked before. What am I missing?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349666/rails3-devise-when-to-nest-resource-in-devise-for-nested-resources

Comment: Sorry, didn't find it in time. Best regards.

Comment: Okay, now the devise routes work. But I still get the same error when I try to access users/1/farms/new. It seems that the Devise User controller is not recognized. How can I access the farm views now?

Comment: Did you rename the devise_for ?

You need to create your own controller called users_controller

Comment: I've managed to get past that error. I should be able to access the farm views via new_user_farm_path(current_user). But I get the: undefined method `farms_path' for #<#<Class:0x719388>:0x26e54b0>

Comment: Try `rake routes` to see which routes are available

Comment: The route is available. It seems that my form for creating farm makes a problem. So, I've added @user in my form: 

  <%= form_for([@farm, @user]) do |f| %>

And in my farm controller, I have:

  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  helper_method :current_user

  def new
    @farm = Farm.new
    @user = User.find(current_user)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @farm }
    end
  end

It should be working now, but I still get: 

  undefined method `farm_user_path' for #<#<Class:0x53aa128>:0x53a73f8>

Comment: Sorry it didn't style the comment properly.

Answer (score 0):

your Form should be

`<%= form_for([@user, @farm]) do |f| %>`

To nest correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576654/devise-nested-resource-view-shows-no-method-error